# selecting from two tables and using lateral view hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to select from two tables in Hive, but it seems to be giving me an error

```
select b.item item1, street.id as street_id, street.name as street_name, 
c.color as color_id, 'cities' as city  
from mytable.first b, mytable.second c 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(b.cities) citiestbl as street
```

This gives me a

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10085]: Line 1:120 JOIN with a LATERAL VIEW is not supported 'c'

Comment: If the syntax is not supported, then you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a `cross join` between first and second tables in the query and using a `lateral view`. As the error message suggests, `join` with a `lateral view` isn't supported.

Not sure if you need a cross join, but re-write the query as

```
select bc.item as item1, citiestbl.street, bc.color as color_id, bc.cities as city  
from (select b.item,c.color,b.cities 
      from mytable.first b 
      cross join mytable.second c) bc 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(bc.cities) citiestbl as street 
--Note that citiestbl is a table alias and street is the column-alias for the exploded column
--Only the exploded column can be referred to in the select, which is street in this case
```